# git diff not comparing as expected

Tags: git, diff

I have two files:

one.txt:

```
function drawLabel(l, inheritObj){
if(def(inheritObj)) l = [l, inheritObj];
l = unpack(l);
// alert('label object before defaults: '+l)
```

two.txt:

```
function drawLabel(l, inheritObj){
if(def(inheritObj)) l = [l, inheritObj];
l = unpack(l);
// alert('label object before defaults: '+l)
```

I tried using `git diff one.txt two.txt` on them.  I expected it to tell me that there were NO DIFFERENCES.  Instead, it said this:

```
diff --git a/one.txt b/two.txt
index 641c1d0..3a99d19 100644
--- a/one.txt
+++ b/two.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-function drawLabel(l, inheritObj){
-    if(def(inheritObj)) l = [l, inheritObj];
-    l = unpack(l);
-    // alert('label object before defaults: '+l)
+function drawLabel(l, inheritObj){
+    if(def(inheritObj)) l = [l, inheritObj];
+    l = unpack(l);
+    // alert('label object before defaults: '+l)
```

Not helpful at all.  I needed to compare two large files to look for differences.  I thought git diff would find the differences and show them to me (and nothing else).

How can I get the behavior I expect?

Comment: What does `git diff -w` show?

Comment: Why are you using `git diff` for this, and not simply `diff`? `git diff` only makes sense when the files are tracked by Git. Other than that, it could be whitespace differences.

Comment: What are these files' states? I.e., are they untracked or tracked and if so, what is their relation to the index and repository (what does `git status` say with regard to these files)? I tried to run `git diff one.txt two.txt` with both files tracked and unmodified relative to the repository, and I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using `diff -w` or `diff -b` shows that they are the same.  Therefore I must conclude that there is some weird newline difference that I cannot see.

Using the regular `diff` versus the prettier `git diff` made no relevant difference in this scenario.  I checked both in all cases and they behaved the same.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Are there some not visible characters for example at the end of each line?

http://www.codealpha.net/514/diff-and-ignoring-spaces-and-end-of-lines-unix-dos-eol/

edit: okay, this is `git diff -w`